# SharePoint Server Low Disk Space issue

Tags: service-applications

My wfe c: drive sapce is shows zero..but wfe2 is shows 32 GB..(ram is 16GB)..but my sharepoint logs is pointed in D drive only

My environment :  2 app server , 2 wfe  and 1 sql cluster..

Any impact due to low disk space in wfe1..?

at present sites are working..please advice me...if issue exist what will happened sharepoint sites ?/

Answer (score 2):

There is a risk of server instability by not having free disk space on C drive.  For example memory management and Windows being able to write to system files.  You could set the NLB load to 100% for wfe2 while you fix the issue to prevent users experience any issues accessing wfe1.  This will also allow you to reboot the server if necessary.

Confirm other files are not installed on your wfe server - e.g. if you have a session state SQL server on there, you may have SQL data files on your C drive.

Check your memory settings, for some reason your page file may be full and after a restart or for some reason it is not being cleaned up.

Check your SP logs and system log files have not got too large.  Confirm the location of your SharePoint and IIS logs.

Obvious one, check your recycle bin etc. for any large files that may have been put on the C then deleted (and not purged from the recycle bin).

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely important that there be sufficient storage space in place on each and every server to support your environment or you will have stability issues and a general performance impact.  There are non-SharePoint things that will be written to the disk, there are system logs, as well virtual memory.  As disks fill up, they will slow down further.  Without sufficient space, your servers will have a harder time coming back from a crash and will not be able to do the memory dumps as Russell mentioned.

The Health Analyzer rules are going to look for 5x available RAM to be freely available.  In your case that is 80GB of ram that should be available at all times.  When doing capacity planning it is important to make sure that you have enough space.

Here is the SP 2010 Capacity Planning Guide:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261700.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is because the health analyzer log file .usage get stored in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\" and do not get deleted once they all moved to the sql database. perhaps its not getting moved to the sql server..

Microsoft has released a cumulative update to fix this issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2916922

i had the same issue and now its solved

Answer (score 0):

- access the files inside the logs folder and deleted all log file of each server.

  - C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS
  - C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
- Delete temp file server
- Shrink SQL server databases (SharePoint)
- Windows Fabric Log
  C:\ProgramData\Windows Fabric\Fabric\log\Traces
  [image]

[image]